# jQuery, get each value from a list and wrap it with <a href="same value">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four lists

```
<li class='lists'>http://google.com</li>
<li class='lists'>http://facebook.com</li>
<li class='lists'>http://twitter.com</li>
<li class='lists'>http://youtube.com</li>
```

I want to wrap an `a` tag around the values of this lists with `href=` value from the values in the list.

The end result I am trying to achieve is:

```
<li class='lists'><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></li>
<li class='lists'><a href="http://facebook.com">http://facebook.com</a></li>
<li class='lists'><a href="http://twitter.com">http://twitter.com</a></li>
<li class='lists'><a href="http://youtube.com">http://youtube.com</a></li>
```

So far I did with jQuery

```
$('li.lists').wrapInner('<a class="links"> </a>');
```

which wraps contents inside `li` with `a` tags, but I am little short on logic how to put the links into the `a` field.

I tried with

```
$.each($('.links'), function() {
  $('.links').attr({'href':$(this).text()});
})
```

But this changes all the links to the `http://youtube.com` which is the last link, as you can see in the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vt8WR/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can continue to use wrapInner. Just use this syntax:

```
$('li.lists').wrapInner(function () {
    return "<a href='" + $(this).text() + "'></a>";
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TMQ2F/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You're close with your last example. Try this:

```
$('.lists').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).text();
    $(this).html($('<a>').attr('href', href).text(href));
});
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vt8WR/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('li.lists').html(function (_, old_html) {
    return '<a href="' + old_html + '">' + old_html + '</a>';
});
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vt8WR/1/)</kbd>

---

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml)

Answer (score 1):

As [this jQuery article](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/) mentions, $.each is used for non-JQuery objects while .each() is used for jQuery objects. Since you're setting the href attribute of each  tag using the jQuery selector, you'll want to use .each() in such a way to set both the  tag with wrapInner and its href:

```
$('.lists').each(function() {
    $(this).wrapInner('<a class="links"> </a>');
    $(this).children('a').attr({'href':$(this).text()});
})
```

**[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vt8WR/4/)**

Comment: Ok, well that's better, but now the code in your answer doesn't match the code in your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and article, I certainly didn't know. The short liner by @j08691 was more favorable in my case.

Comment: @JhilkeDai I agree I like j08691's solution more too :-) updated my solution to cover the whole question instead of just the last part.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
$('.lists').each(function() {
$(this).wrapInner('<a class="links" href="'+$(this).text()+'"> </a>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) for all `li.list` and [$.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) to append the child element(`<a>` tag).

**Demo**

```js
$('li.lists').each((i,el) => {
  let text =$(el).text();
  $(el).text('');
  $(el).append($('<a>').attr('href', text).text(text));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class='lists'>http://google.com</li>
<li class='lists'>http://facebook.com</li>
<li class='lists'>http://twitter.com</li>
<li class='lists'>http://youtube.com</li>
```